# How to recursively iterate for dynamic data

Tags: php, recursion, logic

I've Json data in **PHP** which is:

```
{
  "module": [
    {
      "jhooq-webserver-1": [
        {
          "source": ".//module-1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "jhooq-webserver-2": [
        {
          "source": ".//module-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "provider": [
    {
      "aws": [
        {
          "access_key": "var.access_key",
          "region": "var.web_region",
          "secret_key": "var.secret_key"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All i wanted is to use **recursive function** to convert it to the below format (output):

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "var.web_region"
  access_key = "var.access_key"
  secret_key = "var.secret_key"
}

module "jhooq-webserver-1" {
  source = ".//module-1"
}

module "jhooq-webserver-2" {
  source = ".//module-2"
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using recursive function in php which i failed unfortunately failed. I'm unclear to use recursive function for my scenario.

Comment: Why do you want a recursive function? There's nothing here to recurse. And what's that output format? It's not JSON. Is it just text?

Comment: First, you should show your work, what you tried, and what didn't work about it. Second, @TangentiallyPerpendicular is right, it looks what you want here is to *iterate*, not *recurse*.

Comment: Third, the ask is a little unclear here. For example, your output has `region` first, then `access_key`, but the data has `access_key` first. Do you know that the `provider` will always have exactly these three keys, and you want them to always appear in your specific order?

Comment: Yes. output format is not json. Tricky part is to understand json format to convert to specific output format. The reason for recursive is that i have dynamic & different nested json each time. I've used simple input and output format to explain my point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a recursive function to do this:

```
foreach($array as $blockName => $level2) {
    foreach($level2 as $level3) {
        foreach($level3 as $title => $level4) {
            echo "$blockName \"$title\" {\n";
            foreach($level4 as $level5) {
                foreach($level5 as $key => $value) {
                    echo "  $key = \"$value\"\n";
                }
            }
            echo "}\n";
        }
    }
}
```